# How To Upload Image with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form, the form is including  2 text inputs and 1 file upload input. Text inputs are  working with AJAX. But the file upload is not working with ajax. If i don't use ajax, its working. So my app is completely working, but without ajax, the page has to refresh because its directly going to the php file, but  i dont want that. I want to use AJAX. How can i use ajax for this form?

```js
   $("#form").submit(function(e) {
                
                e.preventDefault();
                
                
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'config.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $("#form").serialize(),
                    success: function () {
                $(".upClass").html("Updated");
                    
                    }
                })
            })
```

```html
  <form id="form" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="site_title">
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                            <textarea class="form-control" name="site_description" ></textarea>
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                     <div class="form-group">
                                                                  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary upClass">Update</button>
                                                    </div>  
</form>
```

I dont share my config.php because its already working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: In this link, some user says: "File upload is not possible through AJAX."  But this post send in 2010. I think in recent years, it can be possible.

Comment: @BerkayO. the "not" is crossed out. it wasn't possible at the time in all browsers, but now is. IE7 in particular didn't allow it and thus required iframe workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's ajax function can send files too, but you must send a FormData:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

//This line replaces the jQuery's serialize function: 
var formData = new FormData($("#form").get(0));
//And then, you can add extra field/values like this, if you need to:
formData.append("dato", "valor");

$.ajax({
   url: 'config.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: formData ,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
     success: function () {
       $(".upClass").html("Updated");
       }
   })
})
```

The `contentType: false` and `processData: false` ensure that the data is send as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', the same way as if it where a normal form submit.

Comment: My bad, fixed. I usually send and receive JSON formatted data.

Comment: Thank you so much, its working for me.